# I'll arrest you. Vs. I'll have you arrested

Tags: word-choice

> Police A: If you keep resisting, I'll have you arrested!
>
> Police B: If you keep resisting, I'll arrest you!

What is the difference between those? Is the police A less likely to arrest him than police B would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I'll arrest you" implies that the speaker will be doing the arrest him/herself. "I'll have you arrested" implies that the speaker needs someone else to to perform the arrest.

Usually a police officer would probably say "I'll arrest you" because a police officer has the authority/ability to arrest you him/herself. A civilian who can cause you to be arrested (e.g. by calling the police) would say "I'll have you arrested".

So, for example, if you are trespassing on someone's property, the owner might ask you to leave and threaten to "have you arrested". The police officer who shows up would ask you to leave and threaten "to arrest you".

Comment: Pretty good answer, except that I would say that a police officer saying "I'll have you arrested" might still mean that he will technically do the arresting himself.  Using "have you arrested" attributes the arrest to "the law" or "justice", with the policeman acting as an agent of "the law" or "justice".  It's an abstract concept, but common and idiomatic.

Comment: @RichardWinters I guess my use of the word “usually” will have to account for the abstract police officer.

Comment: No British police officer would say "I'll have you arrested" when he or she planned to do it themselves.